# Deselect DataGridView rows

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I am using C++/CLI Windows Forms Application.

I have a DVG, and I want to deselect rows by clicking blank area of DVG. I tried several ways, and none of them works.
1)

```
System::Void Form1::dataGridView1_MouseDown(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e) 
    {
        if (e->Button == System::Windows::Forms::MouseButtons::Left)
        {
            if (dataGridView1->HitTest(e->X, e->Y)->Equals(DataGrid::HitTestInfo::Nowhere))
            {
                dataGridView1->ClearSelection();
            }
        }
    }
```

2) This variant causes error (Error 1   error C3063: operator '==': all operands must have the same enumeration type)
)

```
if (e->Button == System::Windows::Forms::MouseButtons::Left)
        {
            if ((dataGridView1->HitTest(e->X, e->Y)->Type) == DataGrid::HitTestType::None)
            {
                dataGridView1->ClearSelection();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of your variable is `dataGridView1`. That implies to me that you're using [`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx), not [`DataGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.aspx). You should be using [`DataGridView::HitTestInfo::Nowhere`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.hittestinfo.nowhere.aspx) instead of `DataGrid::HitTestInfo::Nowhere`, and [`DataGridViewHitTestType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewhittesttype.aspx) instead of `DataGrid::HitTestType`.

In your first example, you're comparing a `DataGridView::HitTestInfo` to `DataGrid::HitTestInfo::Nowhere`. You're calling the `Equals(object, object)` method, so it's a valid line of code, but those are different classes that will never return equal, which is why the selection is never getting cleared.

In your second example, you're comparing a `DataGridViewHitTestType` to a `DataGrid::HitTestType`, which will generate the compiler error.